# F# mysterious differences between piping and function application

Tags: f#, type-inference, piping

Premise: I thought that the piping operator is nothing but syntactic sugar, thus `x |> f` should be exactly the same as `f(x)`.

Analogously, I thought that `f (fun x -> foo)` is equivalent to `let g = fun x -> foo; f g`

But apparently there are differences that I do not understand.

Example 1:

```
static member contents = 
    let files = Directory.EnumerateFiles (__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__+ @"\foo\bar.txt")
    let fileList = List.ofSeq files
    fileList |> List.map (fun f -> TestCaseData(f).SetName(""))
```

This works fine: TestCaseData expects an `arg:obj` which is matched by `f` which in turn in inferred to be a `string` since `fileList` is a list of file names.
However the following does not work

```
static member contents = 
    let files = Directory.EnumerateFiles (__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__+ @"\foo\bar.txt")
    let fileList = List.ofSeq files
    List.map (fun f -> TestCaseData(f).SetName("")) fileList
```

Nothing but the last line has changed. Suddenly `f` is inferred as `obj []` and `TestCaseData` requires an argument of type `obj []` and hence I get an error

```
Error   1   Type mismatch. Expecting a obj [] list but given a string list    
The type 'obj []' does not match the type 'string'
```

I would have thought that both snippets are equivalent in produce correct code but only the first does?!

Example 2:

```
[<TestCase("nonsense", TestName="Nonsense")>]
member x.InvalidInputs str =
    let lexbuf = Microsoft.FSharp.Text.Lexing.LexBuffer<char>.FromString(str)
    Assert.Throws<FatalError> (fun () -> ParsePkg.parse "Dummy path" lexbuf |> ignore)
    |> ignore
```

Above everything works fine.

```
[<TestCase("nonsense", TestName="Nonsense")>]
member x.InvalidInputs str =
    let lexbuf = Microsoft.FSharp.Text.Lexing.LexBuffer<char>.FromString(str)
    let ff = fun () -> ParsePkg.parse "Dummy path" lexbuf |> ignore
    Assert.Throws<FatalError> (ff)
    |> ignore
```

As you see, all I did was pull out the argument of the assertion by first defining `let ff = ...` (for readability reasons, say) and suddenly the compiler points to the `(ff)` argument and complains:

```
Error   2   This expression was expected to have type TestDelegate but here has type unit -> unit
```

TestDelegate is a type of NUnit that I am using here and it happens to coincide with `unit->unit` so I'd assume it would be unified anyway but that does not even matter. Why at all is it possible that the type changes, since again I believe to have done a purely syntactic replacement?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

type inferences is done sequential top to bottom. So in the first case fileList is the first *lexical* argument. 
The information that the fileList is a list of strings is then used in the piping expression. To know whether `string`is a legal type for f the signature of TestCaseData is used. As commented, based on the error message TestCaseData probably accepts `[<Params>] obj []` making a single string argument valid.

In the second version there's no information to use when determining the type of f other than the signature of TestCaseData and therefor `f` is inferred to be of type `obj []`

Similar is true in the other example. Just the other way around. Pulling out the function removes the information that it's supposed to be of type `TestDelegate`.

At the lexical point the only information available is that it's a function of type `unit->unit`.

When the function is used at a program point where a `TestDelegate` is required. The type inference tests whether the function can be used as a `TestDelegate` and if so, infers the type to be `TestDelegate`

Comment: I would also note that, judging by the error message, the `TestCaseData` function probably takes not `obj`, but `[<Params>] obj []`, which works when you try to pass it a single `obj`, but gets inferred as `obj []` when the type of argument isn't known yet.

Comment: This is interesting. Thus the validity of a program not solely depends on syntax and (in principle) valid use of types but actually on the currently implemented type inference mechanism. Thus a given program text can become valid/invalid depending on Microsoft's future implementation of type inference in the compiler? I find it very disturbing that algebraic laws such as `(|>) f x = f x` are valid or invalid depending on what types `f` and `x` have.

Comment: Now I wondering. Could this issue also occur in pure F# code or is it just a problem here because of interaction with .NET (since NUnit is not written in F#)?

Comment: @FriedrichGretz The type inference is not an implementation detail. In these particular cases, you can declare the type specifically and the program would compile just fine. The inference is based on the available information. Whether the types are part of FSharp.Core or mscorlib or any other library is not relevant